# DSL-504T as dumb ADSL modem

Tags: router

I am trying to setup an existing DSL-504T ADSL router to work as a dumb modem for a DIR-825 wifi router. I am assuming I should try and move as much of the control to the DIR-825 as possible. It's a PPPoA connection so I don't think I can use bridge mode.

Does anyone have any guidance on this?
Should I have 2 subnets?
Should I set the DIR-825 as the DMZ on the DSL-504T?
Do I need to keep NAT and firewall enabled on DSL-504T?

Basically I have it working but want to know if I have set it up correctly as I really want the QoS to work on the DIR-825.

Comment: I'm planning the exact same setup, including the need for a couple of port forwaring rules through the 2 boxes.
Out of curiosity, did you find an answer? Can you elaborate on your final setup (as an answer to your own question maybe). TIA

Answer (score 0):

What you basically would want to do is turn off all routing in the DSL-504T (bridged mode) and set PPPOE on the DIR-825. This would cut out double NATting and other potential routing or firewalling issues. Unless you have a really, really good reason to have double NAT set up, don't (DMZs do not completely bypass a firewall, so it allows for potential future problems). QoS would also be setup on the DIR-825, but keep in mind that any QoS rules you set up will only apply up to the router, once they leave your network they are no longer tagged in any recognizable sense for your ISP to route in any special way, and even if they were, your ISP would still route only according to their rules, not yours.